# Append <li> to all <a> links under <ul>

Tags: jquery

I'm using a CMS where I enter in a tag (**{tag_pagination}**) and it renders a functioning pagination link.

The only problem is it does it sloppy by not creating them using a list element and for the Active link, it just renders in plain text, no HTML at all.

It renders as such :

```
<span class="pagination" id="pagination">
   1  
   <a href="/subcat?Page=2&Items=12">2</a>
   <a href="/subcat?Page=3&Items=12">3</a>
   <a href="/subcat?Page=4&Items=12">4</a>
   <a href="/subcat?Page=5&Items=12">5</a>
   <!-- (...) -->
   <a href="/subcat?Page=7&Items=12">7</a>
</span>
<a href="/subcat?Page=2&Items=12">
    <i class="icon icon-arrow-next"></i>
</a>
```

Is there a way I can have this changed to proper Bootstrap pagination?

Comment: I think you have to make that changes into your tag {tag_pagination} because it might be specified there to wrap pagination in <span> instead of <ul>.

Comment: @Nimmi I can't change the layout, I enter in the tag and it pre-generates it, I have no control over what is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add custom CSS to the class pagination or add an existing bootstrap class to it.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp shows how it looks if you use bootstrap.

if you use jQuery you can replace the span with the id pagination with an ul.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that so I tried it but still doesn't have the same effect since it's a classless <a> and plain text

Comment: Try to change the span to a <UL> using your browser to see if that helps.. if it does, ill explain to you how to change this in your code.

Comment: Okay, so I did that and that almost worked. The plain text part got jammed at the right side instead of it's natural position. The plain text part being the Active page. You can see the image here: http://www.screencast.com/t/Un4VokeWfQ

Comment: hmm, that is quite strange :-( unfortunately i cannot help you with that, this was the only solution i knew..

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you to get your solution

```
$('#pagination').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<ul />', {
        html: this.innerHTML,
        id: 'pagination',
        class: 'pagination'
    });
});
$('#pagination').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3}).wrap('<a/>');
$('ul#pagination a').each(function(){
    var ele = $(this);
    var ahref = (typeof ele.attr('href') === 'undefined')?'#':ele.attr('href');
    var atext = ele.html();
    ele.replaceWith('<li><a href="'+ ahref +'">'+ atext +'</a></li>');
});
```

but please still I sugest you to modify your tag ({tag_pagination}) if possible with ul-li. Hope this helps to solve your problem.